How to Prefetch a group concat field in Django
my question is the following :
I have a view table mapped to the Django ORM, with a group_concat field using MariaDB. Is it possible to fetch IDs from this:
This view stores data for operators, and each operator can be associated with multiple companies
Class OperatorsViewExample(models.Model):
  id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_index=True)  # f_operator_id
    fleet_operator = models.ForeignKey(
        "companies.FleetOperator", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        "accounts.MobileUser", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True
    )
    operator = models.ForeignKey(
        "companies.Operator", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True
    )
    companies_shared_str = models.CharField(
        db_column="companies_shared_id", null=True, max_length=4000
    )


companies_shared_str = "1,2,100" are the companies ids where the operator is associated,
f_operator is related with company_id
So I would like to know if the companies_shared_str field is possible to be used in OperatorsView to prefetch in advance, not using a @property because this will lead to N + 1 queries. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

So exactly what is the "input" and output". You have an Operator? You want the companies_shared_strs related to it?
